# how to convert an Array to a linked list in Java

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

I am a fairly new Java programmer and I am currently learning about converting lists to arrays. The problem that I am having is that when I try to link the list the output I am getting is not the same as what is in the array. The linked list output is all null values while the array has random values as it should. 
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class InsertingElements {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] numbers = new Integer[25];
        List<Integer> linkList = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(numbers));

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
        }

        System.out.println("Numbers Generated: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));

        numbers = linkList.toArray(new Integer[linkList.size()]);

        System.out.println("Numbers: ");
        for (Integer number : numbers) {
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
Numbers Generated: [92, 61, 25, 8, 48, 80, 85, 89, 53, 18, 48, 38, 48, 
41, 93, 94, 24, 73, 83, 21, 18, 52, 3, 14, 10]
Numbers: 
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Move `List<Integer> linkList = new LinkedList<> (Arrays.asList(numbers));` to after where you populate the array otherwise your linked list is just a list of default values.

Comment: This does not work on Java 11. Wee need to use: `new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(nums)))`

Comment: @FiReTiTi It works, take a closer look, numbers is `Integer[]` not an `int[]`, and all what `ArrayUtils` from `Apache Commons` does is "boxing" - converting from `int[]` to `Integer[]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

    public class InsertingElements {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Integer[] numbers = new Integer[25];

            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
           }

           List<Integer> linkList = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(numbers));
           System.out.println("Numbers Generated: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));

          numbers = linkList.toArray(new Integer[linkList.size()]);

          System.out.println("Numbers: ");
          for (Integer number : numbers) {
          System.out.println(number);
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

    public class InsertingElements {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Integer[] numbers = new Integer[25];

            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
           }

           List<Integer> linkList = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(numbers));
           System.out.println("Numbers Generated: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));

          numbers = linkList.toArray(new Integer[linkList.size()]);

          System.out.println("Numbers: ");
          for (Integer number : numbers) {
          System.out.println(number);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Just an FYI. When we create a list using a constructor that accepts an array, the list internally iterates the array and adds elements to the list. The list object doesn't hold the reference of the array once the constructor block is executed. That's why @michael 's code is not working.